# What is the snake trying to tell us?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

My friend's pet snake told this below message to us...

What is the message it is trying to tell us? What is the pattern?

> **PL,MKOIJNBHUYGVCFTRDXZSEWAQ**

Comment: @BmyGuest Is the [cipher] tag neccesary?

Comment: @Mithrandir Based on the solutions so far, likely not. When I edited it in, I thought so based on "What is the message?"  I think OP should clarify.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this pattern represents

> Snaking across the keyboard

But the message that I get from the snake is

> "**I'm going to escape**" because, at the end, it's headed towards the **escape** key.

Comment: Hmm... nope, what *you* get doesn't apply, because it stops at the **Q** key.

Comment: maybe he wants to drink some tab

Comment: Maybe it's number one?

Answer (score 31):

Well, the pattern is

> a zigzag path across the keyboard,

but I'm not a Parselmouth, so I don't understand the message.

Comment: People used to use that pattern(at least I did) when playing the snake game back in the day, might be a reference to that.

Answer (score 19):

Well, he is trying to say

> I'm bored.

As per definition mentioned here

> http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plmkoijnbhuygvcftrdxzsewaq

Comment: i think this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 16):

It is trying to tell you that

> your Caps Lock is on.  Otherwise, the text would be "pl,mkoijnbhuygvcftrdxzsewaq"

For a specific reason,

> the snake could not type those capital letters without the Caps Lock being on, since it has no hands/fingers to hold down Shift.

Answer (score 10):

Well the snake is trying to say,

> the snake don't like to be with your friend.

Explanation

> if the snake followed the pattern, path would be like W-A-SHIFT ,SHIFT-CAPS-LOCK-Q like this.[image: Keyboard] so avoiding shift and caps lock means, **snake doesn't like shifting it's natural habitat(forest) to your friend's place and snake doesn't like to be kept in lock.**

Comment: So, why did it skip space, Alt, the Windows key, and the top row (digits and `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, etc.)?

Comment: the initial pattern is 3 keys in zig-zag.

Comment: Wait, really? That's it? That makes no sense.

Comment: even I'm shocked! :D

Answer (score 4):

Pattern:

> I think the sinuous pattern goes from left to right, not right to left.  The reason being that the Q-A-W-E-S-Z looks more like the tail of a snake to me, than the head, as it makes tighter turns.  So I think P is the head.

What the snake is telling us:

> With P as the head of the snake, it's pointing at the -, + and = keys. The snake is identifying itself as an Adder.

Answer (score 2):

I think the snake is trying to say:

> It's feeling out of sorts

because

> though it has traversed the entire alphabet, it has done so in a snakelike way across the keyboard and not any normal order (sort)

Answer (score 0):

> A snake

Reasoning

> The pattern is a zig-zag across the keyboard (thanks @PeregrineRook). That zig-zag suggests a folded snake to me. Especially the **WAQ** part, which suggests a head.

Answer (score 0):

Reading that sentence as:
PL,MKOIJNBHUYGVCFTRDXZSEWAQ

and also as backwards appears as a zigzag on keyboard as:
QAWESZXDRTFCVGYUHBNJIOKM,LP

Since he is speaking of snake, it can be a snake that can go in both(forward and backward) directions in zigzag pattern.

Since snakes's muscle does allow it movement in backward direction,analysis ended in a "snake that **appear** to go in both direction in zigzag pattern"

There are certain snakes whose tail has similar features of its head which belong to sea snakes.

So the snake is telling that its one of those sea snakes which appear to move in both direction in zigzag pattern.

> [image: ![http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01457/snake_1457252c.jpg]

Comment: Your snake picture scared me !!!!

Comment: so do you suggest the characters should be read in reversed order? your conclusion is not really clear for me.