# I have a head but no neck...?

Tags: riddle

> I have a head but no neck
>
> No legs when I check
>
> A tail is there too
>
> I help figure out what to do
>
> Brown in colour
>
> and am smaller than my big brother

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> A penny

I have a head but no neck

> The head on the coin

No legs when I check

> Nope

A tail is there too

> The other side

I help figure out what to do

> According to OP: This is flipping a coin.

Brown in colour

> It is

and am smaller than my big brother

> Smaller than a quarter

What am I?

> A penny

Comment: This is right, well done. Some answers are not what I was thinking but they all work (the one you dont know involves flipping) :)

Comment: I object: you *do* have a neck (in both US and UK varieties).

Answer (score 4):

Is it -

> Snake

I have a head but no neck

> Snake has head ,next part is its whole body.

No legs when I check

> Snake have no legs when it check out of egg maybe.

A tail is there too

> snake has tail.

I help figure out what to do

> Some people treat Snake as god , so ask god what to do??

Brown in color

> snake is in brown color.

and am smaller than my big brother

> small snake might be small than brother.

Comment: It's not right but I like it :)

Comment: This might work better as a worm.  First 3 stay the same, 4th could refer to fishing (they come out when it rains, fish bite better), they are usually some shade of brown.

Comment: "no legs when I check" just is a funny way of saying no legs. Like, "I checked if I had legs -- I looked down -- but I didn't."